# How to exclude advertising libraries from paid app build?

Tags: android, build, gradle

Build file that I'm using is below. I would like to achieve that my paid build contains no advertising libraries. I only include advertising libraries in free flavor. But they are present in all builds.

How should I change my build file to get ad libraries free paid version?

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.5.+'
    }
}

tasks.withType(Compile) {
    options.encoding = "UTF-8"
}

apply plugin: 'android'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    mavenLocal()
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'src/main/libs', include: '*.jar')
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:18.0.+'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:18.0.+'
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 18

    buildToolsVersion "18.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        versionCode 25
        versionName "1.9.1"
        minSdkVersion 9
        targetSdkVersion 18
        packageName 'com.example.myproject'
    }

    signingConfigs {
        debug {
            storeFile file("your path")
        }

        release {
            storeFile file("your path")
            storePassword ""
            keyAlias ""
            keyPassword ""
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        debug {
            packageNameSuffix '.debug'
            versionNameSuffix '-DEBUG'
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
        release {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
    }

    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'src/main/AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src/main/java']
            res.srcDirs = ['src/main/res']
            assets.srcDirs = ['src/main/assets']
        }
    }

    flavorGroups 'market', 'version'

    productFlavors {
        google {
            flavorGroup 'market'
        }
        amazon {
            flavorGroup 'market'
        }
        slideme {
            flavorGroup 'market'
        }
        free {
            flavorGroup   "version"
            dependencies {
                compile fileTree(dir: 'src/free/libs', include: '*.jar')
            }
        }
        paid {
            flavorGroup   "version"
            packageName = android.defaultConfig.packageName + ".paid"
        }
    }

    android.sourceSets.amazon {
        assets.srcDirs = ['src/amazon/assets']
        res.srcDirs = ['src/amazon/res']
        java.srcDirs = ['src/amazon/java']
    }

    android.sourceSets.slideme {
        assets.srcDirs = ['src/slideme/assets']
        res.srcDirs = ['src/slideme/res']
        java.srcDirs = ['src/slideme/java']
    }

    android.sourceSets.free {
        manifest.srcFile 'src/free/AndroidManifest.xml'
        assets.srcDirs = ['src/free/assets']
        res.srcDirs = ['src/free/res']
        java.srcDirs = ['src/free/java']
    }

    android.sourceSets.paid {
        assets.srcDirs = ['src/paid/assets']
        res.srcDirs = ['src/paid/res']
        java.srcDirs = ['src/paid/java']
    }
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

After some research I think I have achieved what I wanted to. By the help from this https://stackoverflow.com/a/17246390/1463357 and this https://stackoverflow.com/a/18213259/1463357 post I was able to fix my gradle.build file.

There was two problems with my original build file. First problem was **wrongly defined dependences** for flavors. Dependencies must be defined **after productFlavors**, and they must be defined in form **flavorNameCompile** like this:

```
productFlavors {
    free {
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'src/main/libs', include: '*.jar')
    freeCompile fileTree(dir: 'src/free/libs', include: '*.jar')
}
```

Second problem was in the **wrong sourceSets definition**. To correctly define sourceSets for flavors, flavors must be defined **before sourceSets**. Like this:

```
productFlavors {
    free {                
    }
}

sourceSets {
    free {
        manifest.srcFile 'src/free/AndroidManifest.xml'
        java.srcDirs = ['src/free/java']
        res.srcDirs = ['src/free/res']
        assets.srcDirs = ['src/free/assets']
    }
}
```

After applying those changes, apk sizes for different flavors were different as expected and no traces of advertising libraries are found in them.

Here is my final gradle.build file:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.6.+'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'android'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    mavenLocal()
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 18

    buildToolsVersion "18.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        versionCode 26
        versionName "2.0"
        minSdkVersion 9
        targetSdkVersion 18
        packageName 'com.example.myproject'
    }

    signingConfigs {
        debug {
            storeFile file("your path")
        }

        release {
            storeFile file("your path")
            storePassword ""
            keyAlias ""
            keyPassword ""
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        debug {
            packageNameSuffix '.debug'
            versionNameSuffix '-DEBUG'
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
        release {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
    }

    flavorGroups 'market', 'version'

    productFlavors {
        google {
            flavorGroup 'market'
        }
        amazon {
            flavorGroup 'market'
        }
        slideme {
            flavorGroup 'market'
        }
        free {
            flavorGroup   "version"
        }
        paid {
            flavorGroup   "version"
            packageName = android.defaultConfig.packageName + ".paid"
        }
    }

    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'src/main/AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src/main/java']
            res.srcDirs = ['src/main/res']
            assets.srcDirs = ['src/main/assets']
        }
        amazon {
            assets.srcDirs = ['src/amazon/assets']
            res.srcDirs = ['src/amazon/res']
            java.srcDirs = ['src/amazon/java']
        }
        slideme {
            assets.srcDirs = ['src/slideme/assets']
            res.srcDirs = ['src/slideme/res']
            java.srcDirs = ['src/slideme/java']
        }
        free {
            manifest.srcFile 'src/free/AndroidManifest.xml'
            assets.srcDirs = ['src/free/assets']
            res.srcDirs = ['src/free/res']
            java.srcDirs = ['src/free/java']
        }
        paid {
            assets.srcDirs = ['src/paid/assets']
            res.srcDirs = ['src/paid/res']
            java.srcDirs = ['src/paid/java']
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'src/main/libs', include: '*.jar')
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:18.0.+'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:18.0.+'
    freeCompile fileTree(dir: 'src/free/libs', include: '*.jar')
}
```

Comment: Hi , in similar way if we want to add some library compile line based on min android api level used for a particular flavour , can we do that ?

Comment: For reference, flavorGroups have been renamed to flavorDimensions. https://stackoverflow.com/a/28233651