# Gradle DSL method not found: 'flavorGroups()'

Tags: android, android-studio, android-ndk, android-gradle-plugin

I'm trying to create a ndk project with android studio according this [tutorial](http://ph0b.com/android-studio-gradle-and-ndk-integration/) and I get this error when I try to sync my gradle:

```
Gradle DSL method not found: 'flavorGroups()'
```

I'm using gradle 2.2.1, with android studio 1.0.2. Here is a part of my gradle file:

```
defaultConfig.versionCode = 1

flavorGroups "abi"

productFlavors {
    x86 {
        flavorGroup "abi"
        ndk {
            abiFilter "x86"
        }
        versionCode = 3
    }
    arm {
        flavorGroup "abi"
        ndk {
            abiFilter "armeabi-v7a"
        }
        versionCode = 1
    }
    mips {
        flavorGroup "abi"
        ndk {
            abiFilter "mips"
        }
        versionCode = 2
    }
    fat {
        flavorGroup "abi"
        versionCode = 0
    }
}

applicationVariants.all { variant ->
    def abiVersion = variant.productFlavors.get(1).versionCode

    variant.mergedFlavor.versionCode = abiVersion * 100000 + defaultConfig.versionCode
}
```

Thank you for your answers.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The Android Gradle pluging received an update which changed the name of `flavorGroups` to `flavorDimensions`. You will also have to change the name of each `flavorGroup` to `flavorDimension`. If you make that change then you won't receive that error any more.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. An update here: In Android 1.2.1.1 Gradle tells me this: 'flavorDimension' will be removed by Android Gradle Plugin 2.0, it has been replaced by 'dimension'.