# Use NDK in android studio 1.5.1?

Tags: android-ndk

I am learning NDK but I can't use from that show me these errors:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: My response is here.Thanks.
[HERE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28233453/gradle-dsl-method-not-found-flavorgroups/28233651)

Answer (score 0):

"First, the Android NDK support **only works with the new experimental Gradle plugin** for Android (which in turn requires Gradle 2.5).
"

Check out http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/android-ndk-preview - there are more info on how to set up Android Studio for NDK and http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/gradle-experimental for list of changes that need to be done when changing gradle plugin to experimental.